# Can I use autocompletion in middle of program in ubuntu? Like at the time of scanf() function

Tags: c

If it is possible, how can I make that option?

My requirement is that, at runtime `scanf()` function is waiting for a input string(file name). At this time I want to perform auto completion option. How can I make that?

For example:

```
printf("enter the sourcefile name\n");
scanf("%s",filename);
```

output terminal
enter the sourcefile name

---

"here I want perform the auto completion option"

please give me explanation with code.

here I post my code please take a note

```
    printf("enter the source file name\n");
    scanf(" %s",filename);
    raw=fopen(filename,"rb");
    if(raw==NULL)
    {
            perror("fopen");
            return;
    }
    int ch;
```

Comment: if you are looking for autocompletion like bash terminal ( on tab or some other key) the nus need to use libreadline library or some equivalent library.

Answer (score 0):

To use the [**GNU Readline Library**](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), you may need to `install libreadline-dev` and compile with the option `-lreadline`. `#include <readline/readline.h>` in your program; you can then replace

```
    printf("enter the sourcefile name\n");
    scanf("%s",filename);
```

with

```
    char *filename = readline("enter the source file name\n");
```